Sbt fails to handle file deleted from ~/.m2 repository
My build.sbt includes this
externalResolvers := Seq(
  "Local Nexus" at "https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-alchemy-public",
  "Maven Central Proxy" at "https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-central",
  Resolver.mavenLocal
)

so it will use my local Maven repo as a source of jars.
I recently deleted a large portion of ~/.m2/repository while trying to resolve an unrelated issue.  Now when I try to do sbt test, I get this error:
[error] (update) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.13/slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar: not found: /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.13/slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar

The jar is available from download via the Maven Central proxy, but it looks like since sbt once found it in .m2, it now wants to always find it there.
I tried to delete any cached info with
find . -name target -exec rm -rf {} +
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1

and while that did result in downloading a lot of files, it still gives the same error.
How do I clear the cached info, so that it attempts to download the jar?
I am using sbt 1.9.7 on a Mac if that matters.
